# When and where was Luciano Pavarotti born, and died?

Tags: history, singers

I heard that Luciano Pavarotti was born in 1935 and had died in 2007.  What was the **specific date** of his birth ans death?  And where was he born/died?

Comment: So what research did you do, if any?    A quick google would have found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luciano_Pavarotti

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luciano Pavarotti was born on 12 October 1935 in Modena, North Italy and  died there on 6 September 2007 from pancreatic cancer. Pavarotti began his career in smaller Italian opera houses. He made his debut at La Scala in 1965 and at the Metropolitan Opera in New York 1972. He became even more famous in 1990 when his rendition of the aria "Nessun dorma" from  Puccini's opera Turandot was taken as the theme for the 1990 FIFA World Cup in Italy. The aria achieved pop status, and became his trademark song. Further details at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luciano_Pavarotti).

Here is an [example](https://youtu.be/cWc7vYjgnTs) that shows him at his best, singing "Nessun dorma" from act 3 of "Turandot".

Comment: The fact I like about him is that "In 1955, he experienced his first singing success when he was a member of the Corale Rossini, a male voice choir from Modena that also included his father, which won first prize at the International Eisteddfod in Llangollen, Wales (UK). He later said that this was the most important experience of his life, and that it inspired him to become a professional singer"  [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luciano_Pavarotti)